# MongooseJS/MongoDB search exact phrase

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to let my users search for exact keyword, for example the user is instructed to enclose keyword with quotes like "Apple" would only search for the exact keyword **Apple**, while without quotes it would search for

```
*Apple*
```

How can I write these queries in MongooseJS? I suppose I should look for quotes in the beginning and end of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right that checking the first and last characters are quotes is probably easiest. However mongoose itself cannot do this. I suggest preparing the query beforehand and also choosing the appropriate *find* method.

We can also use the `$regex` operator to perform the given regular expression against the 'keyword' property of each document in the collection.

```
var userInput = '"Apple"';
var term = userInput.trim(); 
var caseInsensitive = true; // = some user input?

var isExactTerm = (function() {
    var firstChar = term[0];
    var lastChar = term[term.length - 1];
    return (firstChar === '"' && lastChar === '"');
}();

if(isExactTerm) {
    // Remove quotes from the query
    term = term.substr(1, str.length - 1);
}

var method = (isExactTerm) ? 'findOne': 'find';
var regexFlags = (caseInsensitive) ? 'i' : '';
var query = (isExactTerm) ? term : {$regex: new RegExp(term, regexFlags)};

Model[method]({
    keyword: query
}).exec().then(function(result) {
    // do stuff with `result`
}, function(err) {
    // handle `err`
});
```

Comment: if it's exact term shouldn't I remove the quotes before searching? What does the regexp function do?

Comment: Indeed it should. I have edited the answer to remove quotes from the term before performing a query, when necessary. The `$regex` operator performs the given regular expression against the 'keyword' property of each document in the collection. In this case, it returns true if the keyword contains `term`. `RegExp` allows us to construct a regular expression dynamically in runtime.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know a regular expression was needed to match anythingKeywordAnything. How does that regexp work? I just see you create it and supply the term with either the case insensitive flag or empty string?

Comment: The regular expression itself ends up being just the term, and this will match any string that contains `term`. You are correct about the case insensitive flag.

Comment: If I want to match several terms, like I have search term "Apple Event" should match #AppleEvent. Meaning Apple should exist and Event for it to be a match.