# MongooseJS query matching strict and loose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to construct a MongooseJS query in regards to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32059104/294661)

What I have in my MongoDB is a collection called Notifications. The model looks like this:

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    topic: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String, enum: locations, required: true},
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date,
    notifiedAt: Date,
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

The `topic` field can look like this: `"Apple"` or `Apple`.

Now I have an array of topics like `var topics = ["Apple", "AppleEvent", "Android", "Google"]`

If there is a notification with the `topic` field = `Apple` it should match against both `"Apple"` and `"AppleEvent"`

If there is a notification with the `topic` field = `"Apple"` it should strictly only match against `"Apple"`

For best performance how can I construct this query? It's easy enough to just find notifications matching strictly `"Apple"` by using the `$in` operator:

`Notification.find({'topic' : {$in: topics}})`

I can't figure out what is the best way (performance-wise) how to find `*Apple*`? Does it mean that I have to do a query for all notifications in the collection to see which ones that start and end with quotes?

Comment: Well if you were trying to match either "Apple" or "AppleEvent" as stored in the topic, then I would say just use a Regex `/^Apple/`. But you seem to be saying the reverse, where you have an array of `[ "Apple", "AppleEvent"]` that you want to match against possible values of "Apple" in the topic field itself. See the redundancy here? If that array input is under your control then why include both terms? Clearly you expect them to be a "synonym" for each other in terms of matching, so just code your logic to do so and either "remove the duplicate" or "replace it". The pupose is not very clear.

Comment: The alternate here is to "reverse the match" using the JavaScript conditions based in [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). This can be used to basically find if the current "topic" is part of the string in one of the array elements. But as for performance, well it's bad since you cannot use an index to match this way. Thinking of "tags as synonyms" should be a much more perforant approach. But like I said, unclear why both "Apple" and "AppleEvent" should matter to you considering that case.

Comment: I don't have control over the topics array (it's not created by me).

Comment: Does not exactly shed any clarity on the question now does it? What does that mean? Do you mean that this is just random user input? If so then you should be able to control that. Part of programming and design is taking control of silly things that people do and making them rational.

Comment: No no, I get the array data from an external client/source. See the data as news items. Then the users in my app can create notifications to be notified when new news items arrive.